# It is posible to use JOGL (JSR 231) in a web application

Tags: java, mobile-website, gpu, jogl, augmented-reality

I want to do an augmented reality app that runs on mobile devices, but I thing that the best way to do it is with a web application (And I have the advantage that the app will run also on PCs ) so I don't have to care about specific device implementations, I'm a java developer so I'll be so much easier for me if I can use JOGL.

Answer (score 0):

All these [JOGL demos](https://jogl-demos.dev.java.net/) run using [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html), but [JOGL](https://jogl.dev.java.net/) itself is rather resource intensive. In contrast, mobile devices are typically resource limited. I don't see this being a good fit, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Answered without sufficient research .. and understanding of mobile devices .. they can do a lot these days.

Answer (score 0):

JOGL does have an [ES](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg2/jogles1/index.html)(Embedded Systems) version and the OpenGL standard itself has an ES version. Your apps will need to check available JOGL version and cut down what they do if they are in an ES environment. The modern phones especially [Android](http://jmonkeyengine.org/groups/android/forum/topic/android-implementation-of-jmonkey) can support JOGL. You can also use [M3G](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=184), here is a nice link to show which [phones](http://www.jbenchmark.com/result.jsp) you can actually target.